# How to do timing in Simulink using the rem block without getting 0 on t=0?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to make a gain that decreases every x'th second. This is my solution so far:

[image: simulink diagram]

I use an initial value block combined with a switch to make it decrease every time the switch is activated.  To make it switch every x'th second I use the rem function with the time of the simulation an my x'th second.

Every time the rem function outputs zero the switch triggers and everything is well. The problem is at t=0, because then the rem function returns 0 and triggers the switch. This becomes a bigger problem when I try to introduce a delay block between the Time and Rate Transmition3 block, because then the output is 0 for the delayed time and keeps triggering my switch.

Any ideas how to fix this problem? Maybe using a different approach of triggering the switch?

Answer (score 0):

You could put the REM and Switch inside an enabled subsystem with the condition to be enabled if `t>0`. Also, the out of the subsystem should be changed in order to give an initial output that is neutral in your system.

Please let know if this helps. Good luck